# grouping blood tests (binomial distribution)

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Doing some probability problems for fun. Can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong here:

> The army needs to test n soldiers for a disease. There is a blood test that accurately determines when a blood sample contains blood from a diseased soldier. The army presumes, based on experience, that the fraction of soldiers with the disease is approximately equal to some small number $p$.
>
> Approach (1) is to test blood from each soldier individually; this requires $n$ tests. Approach (2) is to randomly group the soldiers into $g$ groups of $k$ soldiers, where $n = gk$. For each group, blend the $k$ blood
>   samples of the people in the group, and test the blended sample. If the group-blend is free of the disease, we are done with that group after one test. If the group-blend tests positive for the disease, then someone in the group has the disease, and we to test all the people in the group for a total of $k+1$ tests on that group. Since the groups are chosen randomly, each soldier in the group has the disease with probability $p$, and it is safe to assume that whether one soldier has the disease is independent of whether the others do.
>
> What is the expected number of tests in Approach (2) as a function of the number of soldiers $n$, the disease fraction $p$, and the group size $k$?

My thought about the approach is as follows:

First, calculate the probability that one or more samples are positive in a group of k samples:
$$p' = 1 - \binom{k}{0}(1-p)^k = 1-(1-p)^k$$

Now, the number of positive pooled samples is binomial distributed with:
$$E[number\ positive\ groups] = gp'$$

since when a group is positive, there will be $k+1$ tests, I would think the expected number of tests would be:
$$E[number\ tests] 
= gp'(k+1) 
= g(k+1)(1-(1-p)^k) 
= gk - gk(1-p)^k + g - g(1-p)^k$$
$$= n-n(1-p)^k + \frac{n}{k} - \frac{n}{k}(1-p)^k$$

The next part of this question asks:

> Show how to choose $k$ so that the expected number of tests using Approach (2) is approximately $n\sqrt{p}$.
>   Hint: Since $p$ is small, you may assume that $(1 - p)^k \approx 1$ and $ln(1-p) \approx -p$.

However, assuming that $(1-p)^k \approx 1$ makes my expected number of positive pooled samples equal to zero. So I'm definitely doing something seriously wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $gp'$ groups are expected to test positive, then $g(1-p')$ groups are expected to test negative.  The total expected number of tests is therefore $$gp'(k+1) + g(1-p'),$$ because negative groups require one test, and positive groups require $k+1$ tests.  Thus the correct expectation is $$\operatorname{E}[\text{Tests}] = \frac{n}{k}(1+k-k(1-p)^k).$$

Comment: Wow, what a dumb oversight on my part. Thanks

Comment: @lstbl No, it most certainly is not a dumb oversight.  I carefully read through your solution at least three times before I realized what was missing.